# Powershell Get-ADgroup show member names inline

Tags: powershell

I've got a script that lists all groups with some details. Amongst others their members. By default members are shown as their DN's. How can I show only their names (eg Jon Doe, Jane Doe, ...).

Currently my code goes as follows:

```
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase $SearchBase -properties $GroupColumns | Where-Object {$_.GroupCategory -eq "Distribution"} | Sort-Object Name | Select-Object $GroupTableHeader
```

This returns all groups with all columns I want. But for the Members-column the content is shown as
**CN=John Doe,OU=Users,DC=company,DC=com CN=Jane Doe,OU=Users,DC=company,DC=com**

Thanks in advance for all help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could issue a Get-ADObject for each member and get just the name but that is an expensive operation. You can use a regular expression to extract the names:

```
$_.Member -replace '^CN=([^,]+).+$','$1'
```

The above captures everything after 'CN=' until the first comma, and replaces the whole string with the match.

Comment: that might work :) But I think my syntax is not correct. This: `Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase "DC=domain,dc=com" -properties members | select-object {$_.Member -replace '^CN=([^,])+.+$','$1'}`only returns an empty '{}' per member

Comment: Try this, it will add a new property to the result called 'Member': Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase "DC=domain,dc=com" -properties members | Select-Object *,@{Name='Member';Expression={$_.Members -replace '^CN=([^,]+).+$','$1'}}

Comment: that worked (and with some trial and error I should have been able to find that out too ;o). Thanks for the tip! I didn't even know Powershell supported regular expressions too.